# Cyclic groups and cryptography

Tags: group-theory, cryptography

Let $m=p_1p_2...p_r$ be a product of distinct primes, and let $U_m$ be the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Let $e$ be the least common multiple of $p_1-1, p_2-1, ..., p_r-1$.

(i) Show that the order of every element $a$ of $U_m$ divides $e$.

(ii) Explain how to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to find an element of $U_m$ of order e.

What I wrote for (i) :

Let $a \in U_m$ and $n$ be the order of $a$ and $n$ divides $e$.
By division algorithm we can write $e=nq+r$ with $q,r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq r<m$.

We have $a^e=1$. But $a^e=a^{nq+r}=(a^n)^q * a^r$.

Since $n$ is the order of $a$, $a^n=1$. Hence, we get $a^r=1$.

Since $0 \leq r <n$ and $a^r=1$, $r$ must be zero because the order of $a$ is $n$.

$r=0$, thus $e=nq$ and finally $n$ divides $e$.

Is that correct? Any idea for (ii)?

Comment: In your proof for (i) in the first line you should NOT say $n$ divides $e$ because if you start with that hypothesis then you are assuming the very fact you are trying to prove.

Comment: What is your justification for $a^e=1$?